# Executing PostgreSql database function or stored procedure from spring boot JPA data initializer

Tags: database, spring, postgresql, jpa, stored-procedures

My database uses some functions to get some stuff done on data, in which I am trying not to have too much outside of code base.

Especially, when we run the application in a different environment like developer's local computer.

I would not to have to always manually create database functions/stored procedure for every Spring boot installation.

I attempted to initialise this using data.sql in /resources/data.sql

It is picking up, but results in errors.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS _wcode_seq
START WITH 8000
MAXVALUE 9999999999999
MINVALUE 1
^;
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS _comcode_seq
START WITH 4000
MAXVALUE 99999999999999
MINVALUE 1
^;

CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS ggg_po_seq
START WITH 2000
MAXVALUE 99999999999999
MINVALUE 1
^;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.createreference()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
begin
if(new.barcode is null) then

 if(new.consignment is true) then
    select nextval('_comcode_seq') into new.barcode;
    new.barcode := 'COM'||lpad(new.barcode,4,'0');
 else
    select nextval('_wcode_seq') into new.barcode;
    new.barcode := 'W'||lpad(new.barcode,4,'0');
end if;
select nextval('_po_seq') into new.po_code;
new.po_code := 'PO'||lpad(new.po_code,4,'0');
end if;

return new;
end^;
$BODY$^;

CREATE TRIGGER _refenence_ts
before insert
on watch
for each row
EXECUTE PROCEDURE createReference()^;
```

My issue maybe a syntax errors, but working well when executed on database GUI(Table Plus)

Comment: The `^` characters look wrong

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , yeah, the ^ was a variation of me trying to solve the error, by adding it before " ; " .